# sqlite how to pass in 2 arguments to a query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following query that returns a Cursor based on how many records have an awayreasontypeid of '2'. It works fine.

How can i run the same query but return a Cursor of all the records that have an awayreasontypeid of either '2' or '0'?

```
// table AwayReason column names
            public static final String C_AWAYREASON_ID_INDEX = BaseColumns._ID;
            public static final String C_AWAYREASON_ID = "awayreasonid";
            public static final String C_AWAYREASON_NAME = "awayreasonname";
            public static final String C_AWAYREASON_TYPE_ID = "awayreasontypeid";

public Cursor queryCarerAwayReasons(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] carer = { "2" };



        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLEAWAYREASON + " WHERE awayreasontypeid = ?", carer);

        return c;

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
String[] carer = { "2", "0" };

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLEAWAYREASON + " WHERE awayreasontypeid IN (?,?)", carer);
```